# How to normalize valid values with jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation

Let us examine a simple scenario, where the user is requested to input a Canadian postal code. The following postal codes are all valid and equivalent:

- H0H 0H0
- h0h 0h0
- h0h0h0

I would like the user to input any of them, but once the field is left to normalize the value to the first form. My `postalCode` validation method indeed allows to enter any of them, however, I wonder what is the right way to normalize the value.

Maybe there is already such a facility in the jQuery validation plugin, I just do not see it.

**EDIT**

Given a function `normalizeInput` I wonder how do I plug it in. Maybe there is a hook in the jQuery validation plugin specifically for that. If not, how to do it so that it is called after the field is left upon successful validation.

Comment: You can thank me, but not adding it to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function normalizePostalCode(s) {
  return s.replace(/(.{3}) ?(.{3})/, '$1 $2').toUpperCase();   
}

var s = "h0h0h0";
s = normalizePostalCode(s); // H0H 0H0
```

It will remove whitespace (`\s`), and convert each letter to uppercase, yielding the first form untouched, and converting the second and third form to the first.

**EDIT**: I don't think jQuery Validation Plugin provides some sort of normalization callback. You could, however, use the [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [`.focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event and check if the field is [`valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid), and if it is, normalize it:

```
$("#txtPostalCode").blur(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.validate();
    if ($this.valid()) {
      $this.val(normalizePostalCode($this.val()));   
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKyD7/)**.

Comment: I have edited my question. So, your reply tells how to implement the `normalizeInput` function, whereas I am interested to know how to plug it in. What I need was not clear initially, sorry.

Comment: Great, thanks. Two questions, though. 1. Why call `$this.validate()`, if  just `$this.valid()` seems to be enough? 2. I changed your `normalizePostalCode`, see http://jsfiddle.net/eXv8J/1/. Do you think it could be written with a single call to regex?

Comment: 1) From my (limited) experience with the plugin, I thought that `valid()` would only work if you had previously called `validate()`. Seems that is no longer the case :). 2) You could use `return s.replace(/(.{3}) ?(.{3})/, '$1 $2').toUpperCase();` for example http://jsfiddle.net/eXv8J/2/.

Comment: Cool, I think it is slower than just manipulate strings in this case, but still this is cool.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Jquery Validate website, there is a method you can include for any given field to normalize a value before it is validated:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/

```

```
$( "#myform" ).validate( {
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      normalizer: function( value ) {
        // Trim the value of the `field` element before
        // validating. this trims only the value passed
        // to the attached validators, not the value of
        // the element itself.
        return $.trim( value );
      }
    }
  }
} );
```

```

But this is on a field-by-field basis only, by the looks of it.

Comment: Don't forget to include the additional-methods.min.js if wanting to apply the normalizer method.

Answer (score 0):

I've added my own white-space method ,

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      jQuery.validator.addMethod("whitespace", function(value, element) { 
       return $.trim( value );
     }, 'whitespace is not allowed'); 
    });

// in rules
    rules: {
      street: {
        whitespace: true, 
        email: true
      },
    }
```